# Page moves after fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery programming and want to solve page changes after fading effect.
I heard that using callback method. but don't know how to use please give me some advice!!!
"Scene2.html" is where I want to move.

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
$("#first").fadeOut(1500);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="first" src="images/Logop.jpg"/>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the docs... http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: `fadeOut` it runs only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it this way:

```js
jQuery(function(){
$("#first").fadeOut(1500, function() {
 window.location.href = 'Scene2.html';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="first" src="http://cdn.hark.com/images/000/003/249/3249/original.jpg">
```